# Datatables display data in table and another section

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I want to show the same data in 2 sections (table and div). Something like that:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>03-07-2023</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div>
    <p>
        <span>Name:</span>
        <span>John Doe</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span>Date:</span>
        <span>03-07-2023</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Datatables code:

```
var table = $("table").DataTable({
    searching: true, 
    paging: false, 
    info: false,
    ordering: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 'data.php',
        type: 'POST'
    }
});
```

I tried to loop through data returned with Ajax after success event:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

but this prevents data loaded into the table and it just keeps loading. Is there a way to loop through data to show it in 2 different sections?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the data before you initialize datatable you can do whaterver you want with them:

HTML: First an empty table/div - just heading:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>              
</table>
<div></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON( "post.php", function(response) {
        let tabledata = [];
        let divdata = [];
        $.each(response, function(i, item){
            tabledata.push('<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td>');
            tabledata.push('<td>' + item.date+ '</td></tr>');

            divdata.push('<p><span>Name:</span><span>' + item.name + '</span></p>');
            divdata.push('<p><span>Date:</span><span>' + item.date + '</span></p>');
 
            $('table').find('tbody').append(tabledata.join(''));
            $('div').html(divdata.join(''));
                
        }
        $("table").DataTable({your options});
    }
});
```